# Swift - How to use TestFlight version of app parallel to the version you develop with XCode

Tags: ios, xcode, app-store-connect, testflight

I have an existing project. I also have a basic version of the app approved for beta testing.

How can I install this "TestFlight" beta version as a separate app to my device? So that I still have the version that I'm developing?

I read through some articles, they're saying you need to have different `App ID`'s. But I'm not sure if that's what I need (could be, I don't know)

Example article: [nilsou.com - How to have two versions of the same app on your device](http://nilsou.com/blog/2013/07/29/how-to-have-two-versions-of-the-same-app-on-your-device/)

There, I have to create a new `APP ID` for the beta version (though in my case I think I have to add 2 `ID`'s, one for XCode versions and one for beta versions). 
**But does that mean I have to create a new app inside of iTunes Connect?**
I thought iTunes Connect works with these `APP ID`s. What if I now have multiple `APP ID`'s for my app?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: What exactly are you trying to achieve? Even with both versions with the same app ID, you can always override the dev version with the TestFlight version and vice versa. If you want to have both versions installed at the same time, just change the app ID for your Xcode builds to avoid overwriting the one downloaded from TestFlight.

Comment: Where can I change the app ID for my Xcode builds? And doesn't this affect the iTunes Connect app or something? I'm sorry if I'm being unclear, but I have know idea myself, what exactly I want to do. I just want to have 2 versions of the same app

Comment: In Xcode's project navigator (first tab of the column on the left), click on the top-most item. Click on the target for your project, and make sure you're on the General tab. Change the "bundle identifier". As long as you don't try to upload a new version to iTunes Connect, you'll be able to run the app with this new ID (Xcode will generate the required certs and profiles for you).

Comment: Note that this might affect things that rely on the bundle ID, like push notifications, iCloud storage, etc, so YMMV.